# Can't open shp2pgsql on Windows 10

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I am trying to open shp2pgsql.exe to import shapefile to PostgreSQL. But something happens because shp2pgsql never displays an opening window. For a very little time it seems it will open a window. Unfortunately  this window suddenly disappears. It never gets opened. I'm using Windows 10,  PostgreSQL 10, pgAdmin 2.1. I have just downloaded PostgreSQL and PostGIS this is the first time I'm using them.

Comment: *Exactly* how are you trying to run shp2pgsql.exe? From a command prompt, double clicking the exe, from the start menu, something else...?

Comment: Double click on exe located in PostgresSQL->10->bin

Comment: shp2pgsql.exe has no GUI, so no window will pop to the screen. Open a cmd-Window, cd to the folder an run shp2pgsql from the prompt. By the way, there should be a gui-Version too.